# How to set minWidth Container in Expand

Tags: flutter, web, flutter-layout

I using flutter to build the Web Application,
I have a response problem, I want my window to be as small as 600 dp, and when zoomed horizontally, the middle container will automatically scale, but the smallest is 200 dp.
I tried to write the code as follows, but it doesn't work as I expected. When I shrink to width less than 600, main container keeps automatically shrink and shrink to less than 200 db.

```
 Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 600,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              ),
             
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 300),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  child: BlocBuilder<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
                      builder: (context, state) {
                    return state.widget;
                  }),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 600,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ConstrainedBox` instead of regular `Container`?
It has properties minHeigth and minWidth / maxHeight and maxWidth.

Comment: I tried. But it still is. It don't work like what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found that ConstrainedBox's minWidth is ignored in Row widget.
So I implemented center widget's dynamic width by using 'MediaQuery' like what you want.

But if you decrease width, the overflow issue is happened.
So I changed Row widget to ListView widget to fix overflow issue.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double centerWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 480;
    return ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 600,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              ),
             
              Container(
                width: centerWidth < 300 ? 300 : centerWidth,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 150, ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  'Hello, World!',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
              ),

              Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 600,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
              ),
            ],
          );

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried. But it still is. It don't work like what I want.

Comment: @TrầnVănHiếu I updated for another solution.

Comment: Thank you. this seems like a good idea. I have achieved what I wanted.

Comment: @TrầnVănHiếu Did you mean that you found more good solution? If that, would you let me know that?